# Exercise on cointegrated processes

Tags: time-series, self-study, cointegration

I have this time series problem that I cannot solve:

> Considering two I(1) independent stochastic processes $z_t$ and $x_t$ and a stationary stochastic process $w_t$, I have the following DGP: 
>   $$
> y_t=x_t+z_t+w_t.
> $$
>   Suppose that I misspecify the DGP and regress $y_t$ only on $x_t$ and $z_t$.
>   Will I be able to find cointegration between $x_t$ and $z_t$? For which conditions?

What I understood thus far, is that the variability of the I(0) process in estimating the wrong DGP will be embedded in the I(1) variables. But I don't know how to deal formally with the problem.

Comment: @RichardHardy sorry no, I restated the problem

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: What I understood thus far, is that the variability of the I(0) process in estimating the wrong DGP will be embedded in the I(1) variables. But I don't know how to deal formally with the problem